# iOS app:: Google+ integration- Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded

Tags: ios

iOS app: - I am integrating google+ API in my iPhone application, i downloaded google+ API through this link:- "https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sdk/google-plus-ios-sdk-1.0.0.zip".

I have successfully integrated it in my code, but when i am trying to get user information, it is giving me error **"The operation couldn’t be completed. (Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.)",**

Any idea about this..!!  Why this error comes.?

Answer (score 4):

It says "All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key."
So you should get an API key and pass it as a parameter
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z12gtjhq3qn2xxl2o224exwiqruvtda0i?key=YOUR-API-KEY

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when you are already logged in and still try to login again and again. I faced same error so did some experiments 
1) I opened website on my mobile and everything was fine. 
2) Then i tried on another laptop and used different gmail account to login and it again worked fine. 
3) On my first laptop i tied again by clicking "Signin" button i got same error, so i opened google.com then logged out completely and then tried again, this time it worked.
  So i believe, Issue is clicking login button again and again without logout.

I am not sure if this is a really a issue, but atleast this is what i found. I am still trying, trying and trying , will post if i found anything else.

Cheers !!